# property of type Class

Tags: objective-c

I have a property of type Class. ie:

```
 @property (nonatomic, Strong or Weak?) Class myClass;
```

Should it be a strong or a weak reference?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use whatever you want to.... nothing will change in this case...

Comment: @nickfalk No, this one here is especially about Class objects.

Comment: Sorry, my bad didn't note the missing pointer-ref. (I read the question as an abstraction, i. e. Class could be AnyCustomClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can safely be `unsafe_unretained` since classes are never released.